# Print Value from vector of integer pointer

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I have created a vector of integer, how to dereference in vector to print the values

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main ()
{
  std::vector<int*> myvector;
  for (int i=1; i<=5; i++){
    myvector.push_back(&i);
  }
  std::cout << "myvector contains:";
  for (std::vector<int*>::iterator it = myvector.begin() ; it !=myvector.end(); ++it){
    std::cout << ' ' << (**it);//?????????//how to print value of vector
  }
  std::cout << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `&1` is not an address.

Comment: *std::vector<int*> myvector;* Vector of integer?

Comment: &1 was the typo i just corrected it.

Answer (score 3):

`myvector.push_back(&i);` does not what you think it does. The variable `i` only exists within the scope of the `for` loop, so storing its address wont work as expected, and the address will most likely be the same. This is undefined behaviour:

On my platform the output is:

```
 6 6 6 6 6
```

instead of

```
 1 2 3 4 5
```

And you missed a `*` (see comment in code below). So you probably want this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::vector<int*> myvector;
  for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {

    myvector.push_back(new int(i));  // new int() allocated a new pointer to int
                                     // and puts i there
  }
  std::cout << "myvector contains:";

  for (std::vector<int*>::iterator it = myvector.begin(); it != myvector.end(); ++it) {
                   // ^<<<<<<<<<<<< you missed this *
    std::cout << ' ' << **it;
  }
  std::cout << '\n';

  // and now we need to delete the allocted pointers

  for (std::vector<int*>::iterator it = myvector.begin(); it != myvector.end(); ++it) {
    delete *it;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

But having a vector of pointers to integers is rather pointless, you probably want just a vector of `int`. Then you need this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> myvector;
  for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {

    myvector.push_back(i);
  }
  std::cout << "myvector contains:";

  for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = myvector.begin(); it != myvector.end(); ++it) {
    std::cout << ' ' << *it;
  }
  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

In C++11, you can write this to iterate through the vector:

```
for (auto & i: myvector) {
  std::cout << ' ' << i;
}
```

which is much simpler.

Comment: hmmm. I would not use `new` and `delete` anymore in modern C++. A `std::unique_ptr` seem more appropriate...

Comment: @JHBonarius that's true, but anyway, using a vector of pointers to int instead of a vector of int is probably not the right choice here anayway.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you simply did a typo in reaching the minimum code:  `myvector.push_back(&1);`. So I skip it and move forward to your question.

If `std::vector<int> myvector` (in the question):

```
for (const auto v : myvector){
  std::cout << ' ' << v;
}
```

If `std::vector<int*> myvector` (in the title):

```
for (const auto p : myvector){
  std::cout << ' ' << *p;
}
```

**UPDATE**

`myvector.push_back(&i);` is also incorrect. You push a pointer to the locally scoped variable `i`. There is two problems:

1. The same local variable address is pushed in each iteration.
2. You get dangling pointer after `for` and undefined behavior.

Comment: @AkankshiMishra Do not forget to `delete` allocated `int`, or declare the vector `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> myvector` to auto `delete` allocated ints after vector is destroyed.

Comment: @AkankshiMishra That example is correct. The variable `p1` is declared in the function scope, not in the loop scope. Choose and vote for the answer you like.